# In Angular 6, providing route path via array throw error

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I Angular 6 application, I am passing angular routes from service class in format

```
{ text: string, path: string }
```

so the idea is I add routes dynamically, which works fine if I provide data statically, however if I replace same structure as providing data via array, it throw error,

I strongly believe is related to array structure, the way need to pass it to router.config.unshift. The unshift method accept array of Router where I am passing array of any.......

### error

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at defaultUrlMatcher (router.js:530)

### route service

```
 @Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
 })

export class DynamicRoutingService{

messages: string[] = [];

constructor(){}

getDynamicRoutes():any{ // need fix here to pass Route[]
 return [
    { path: 'publicSurvey', component: SurveyFormComponent },
    { path: 'RedMatter', component: SurveyFormComponent },
    { path:'waterDamAndBridge', component:SurveyFormComponent}
  ];
 }
}
```

### app component

```
export class AppComponent {

 constructor(
   private router: Router,
   private routingService:DynamicRoutingService
 ){

  let dynamicRoutes = this.routingService.getDynamicRoutes();

  this.router.config.unshift(dynamicRoutes); // this line throw error


  /*  following disable code does work
   this.router.config.unshift(
  { path: 'publicSurvey', component: SurveyFormComponent },
  { path: 'RedMatter', component: SurveyFormComponent },
  { path:'waterDamAndBridge', component:SurveyFormComponent}
);*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

`this.router.config.unshift(...dynamicRoutes);`

Comment: this did worked but not really getting what happened and how three dots helped here

Comment: For this case, **destructuring assignment unpacks values from the array**. Just click the link on the answer to read more.